# Quadratic equation program is not giving values

Tags: c#, console, quadratic

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code for solving a quadratic equation?
Don't be cringed out by my work, because I'm still very new to the program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a, b, c, x1, x2, x, D;
        String A;
        String B;
        String C;
        Console.Write("a=");
        A = Console.ReadLine(); 
        Console.Write("b=");
        B = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("c=");
        C = Console.ReadLine();
        a = Convert.ToDouble(A);
        b = Convert.ToDouble(B);
        c = Convert.ToDouble(C);
        D =(b * b - 4 * a * c);
        if (D > 0)
        {
            x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
            Console.WriteLine("x1=" + x1);
            Console.WriteLine("x2=" + x2);
        }
        else
            if (D < 0)
            {
                D = -D;
                x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
            }
            else
            {
                x = (-b / (2 * a));
                Console.WriteLine("x=" + x);
            }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

It doesn't display any values when it is run.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working with your code so far.

Comment: Well, when i run it, i don't get any values.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a, b, c, x1, x2, x, D;
        String A;
        String B;
        String C;
        Console.Write("a=");
        A = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("b=");
        B = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("c=");
        C = Console.ReadLine();
        a = Convert.ToDouble(A);
        b = Convert.ToDouble(B);
        c = Convert.ToDouble(C);

        if (a != 0)
        {
            D = (b * b - 4 * a * c);

            if (D > 0)
            {
                x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                Console.WriteLine("x1=" + x1);
                Console.WriteLine("x2=" + x2);
            }
            else
            {
                if (D < 0)
                {
                    D = -D;
                    //x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                    //x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);

                    string complexX1 = ((-b) / (2 * a)).ToString() + "+" + (Math.Sqrt(D) / 2 * a).ToString() + "i";
                    string complexX2 = ((-b) / (2 * a)).ToString() + "-" + (Math.Sqrt(D) / 2 * a).ToString() + "i";

                    Console.WriteLine("complex x1=" + complexX1);
                    Console.WriteLine("complex x2=" + complexX2);
                }
                else
                {
                    x = (-b / (2 * a));
                    Console.WriteLine("x=" + x);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (b != 0)
            {
                x = -c / b;

                Console.WriteLine("Grade 1 equation");
                Console.WriteLine("x=" + x);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No equation.");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It seems that you were not writing to console in all the cases.

And also the way how the complex roots were treated was not entirely correct since the "i" was missing so that the real and imaginary part of the number were missing. Now the result should be fine also for complex roots.

I updated the code so now also cases when a is 0 (the equation is not quadric) and b is 0 (there is no equation) are handle.

Comment: May I know who down voted my answer and why ? The answer is really a nice solution for a quadric equation.

Comment: Probably someone who is not understanding Math :).

Comment: You're welcome ! Please do not forgate to mark the answer :D.

Comment: So i tried the code, and it does give right numbers, but they're negative, though the shouldn't be.

Comment: Just post your values for a,b and c and i will check

Comment: Oh, it was my fault. I typed in 9 instead of -9. The equation was a^2-9a+20

Comment: When working with *complex* values (roots in the case) why not suing `Complex` structure which is specially desinged for that purpose? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think that for a begginer is better to keep things simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Do not cram everything into a single `Main` method, decompose your implementation! 
In your very case, let's extract a method:

```
   // IEnumerable<Double>: quadratic equation can have 0..2 distinct real roots  
   private static IEnumerable<Double> SolveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
     double D = b * b - 4 * a * c;

     if (D < 0)
       yield break; // No real solutions (they are both complex ones)
     else if (D == 0)
       yield return -b / (2 * a); // One distinct root    
     else {
       // Two distinct solutions
       yield return (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a); 
       yield return (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a); 
     }
   }
```

Then use it:

```
   ...
   a = Convert.ToDouble(A);
   b = Convert.ToDouble(B);
   c = Convert.ToDouble(C);

   var result = SolveQuadratic(a, b, c)
     .Select((x, i) => $"x{i + 1} = {x}");  

   Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));

   Console.ReadKey();
```